# Why is the shape operator self adjoint regarding the first fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry

Why is the shape operator $A: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R^2 $self adjoint regarding the first fundamental form? I see it is written as a fact everywhere but cannot find a proof for it.

Comment: See Wolfgang Kuhnel's book on Differential Geometry (third edition), page 67.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found out myself that it is equivalent to the symmetry of the 2nd fundamental form.